# How To set Media element in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [adding media element in windows phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287360/adding-media-element-in-windows-phone-7)

I Want Details Explanation and Code  For How To Set MediaElement In Windows Phone 7?

Comment: Hi Can u Give Detail idea about .when click on particualr image that particular sound can play  only .in the same way all image sounds are played successfully when click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric's post in [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/96c5e949-17dd-41f8-8331-0f7972634ad6) thread covers this.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth mentioning that Windows Phone 7 currently only supports a single MediaElement (as explained by Peter Torr at Tech Ed this year, this is mainly for performance reasons).

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426928(VS.96).aspx for more details.