# adding media element in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to play an audio of  an image whenever click on it .If we click on another image that sound will play in that way we want write the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're binding to an object that has the image uri and audio clip uri:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Tag="{Binding AudioPath} MouseLeftButtonDown="img_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
```

then in the event handler

```
    void img_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender,MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
Image img = sender as Image;
if (img != null)
mePlayer.Source = img.Tag as Uri;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

i dont recommend mediaElement for more than one audio item ..it has weird effects ...use something like:

Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream(@"Audio/buzzer.wav");

```
        SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
        FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
        effect.Play();
```

using the xna framework ....