# media element doesn't play audio in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [adding media element in windows phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287360/adding-media-element-in-windows-phone-7)

media element doesn't play audio even correctly giving the properties.

Comment: You've not told us anything about what you've tried or shown us any code.  It will be very difficult for anyone to even guess what you might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It does work.

In code:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;

var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("beep.wav");
                var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
                effect.Play();
```

N.B. "beep.wav" must be configured as "Content".

In app constructor add:

```
this.ApplicationLifetimeObjects.Add(new XNAAsyncDispatcher(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50)));
```

Also add the following class:

```
public class XNAAsyncDispatcher : IApplicationService
{
    private DispatcherTimer frameworkDispatcherTimer;

    public XNAAsyncDispatcher(TimeSpan dispatchInterval)
    {
        this.frameworkDispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        this.frameworkDispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(frameworkDispatcherTimer_Tick);
        this.frameworkDispatcherTimer.Interval = dispatchInterval;
    }

    void IApplicationService.StartService(ApplicationServiceContext context) { this.frameworkDispatcherTimer.Start(); }
    void IApplicationService.StopService() { this.frameworkDispatcherTimer.Stop(); }
    void frameworkDispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) { FrameworkDispatcher.Update(); }
}
```