# my Shoutcast stream doesnt play using WP7 MediaElement

Tags: windows-phone-7, streaming, mediaelement, shoutcast

I need help with this issue, I'm trying to use MediaElement in Windows Phone 7.5 to play an audio stream

Code is simple

```
<MediaElement Source="http://ghost.wavestreamer.com:9122/listen.mp3" AutoPlay="True" />
```

But no audio is getting played!

This is the stream I want to play
http://ghost.wavestreamer.com:9122/listen.mp3

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

***These links can help u in figuring isse and creating ur app.***

**adding media element in windows phone 7?**

[adding media element in windows phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287360/adding-media-element-in-windows-phone-7)

**media element doesn't play audio in windows phone 7?**

[media element doesn't play audio in windows phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288744/media-element-doesnt-play-audio-in-windows-phone-7)

**Using Smooth Streaming Media Element for Windows Phone 7**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/giuseppeguerrasio/archive/2010/12/06/using-smooth-streaming-media-element-for-windows-phone-7.aspx

**Overcoming Windows Phone 7 MediaElement limitations**

http://spacemigas.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/overcoming-windows-phone-7-mediaelement-limitations/

**Resuming streaming audio from Dormant/Tombstone state in WP7**

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Resuming_streaming_audio_from_Dormant/Tombstone_state_in_WP7

**Using MediaElement to Play audio before it is fully downloaded and the dreaded AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR**

http://forums.silverlight.net/t/227000.aspx