# Windows Phone 7.1 - Media Element not playing

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

Windows Phone 7.1/7.5/Mango app.

I have four different MediaElements on the page.

- One is played upon Load of the page.
- Rest 3 I Play() it upon leftMouseButtonClick on different image element on the page.
  I call Stop() in the MediaEnded event handler.

**Issue:** The last mediaElement in the top-down order won't play. So it's not the element itself bu the order of the element that is behaving weird.

I have [read this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/96c5e949-17dd-41f8-8331-0f7972634ad6) where it talks about a single MediaElement which I don't understand.

Does anyone has any ideas on this?

**Note:** I don't have to play all sound at the same time. Only one sound at a time.

I found one reference that talks having single MediaElement only and dynamically set the Source in the code. I haven't tried it yet, will do soon.

Comment: Get us some xaml markup and some C# code, and then we'll be able to help. Thus far, having 4 media elements of the page sounds fine. Everything should work.

Comment: There isn't anything facny but I will put up the code later in the evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To confirm your last sentence, you can only have one `MediaElement` per page. You'll have to consider changing the source from the code-behind (or using data-binding) instead of having a `MediaElement` for each piece of audio. Having multiple MediaElements won't throw an error, but it will just override the behaviour of the previously added one (like you're experiencing).

To set the audio from the code-behind, you can use either the [SetSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.setsource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (which accepts a stream) method, or the [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.setsource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property which reads a `Uri`.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my question, I know that and am going to try that later in the evening but mainly what's confusing is 3 Elements are working fine, the 4th(the last in order) won't.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to expect erratic behaviour if you're going to use unsupported methods. Even if it worked for you with all four, you shouldn't really be using multiple MediaElements as there's absolutely no reason to.

Comment: Yes, as coder I like less elements as well wherever possible. Designer is using Blend to create the app and that's when we ended up with multiple elements. But one place I see is we have a UserControl that has one of the MediaElement. This user control is used on most of the pages. So at the minimum I see having two MediaElements on my page.

Comment: You could use a static MediaPlayer accessible from the entire app. Alternatively, you could provide access to the MediaPlayer on a page so that the user control can communicate with the particular MediaPlayer on the page.

Comment: Implemented using single MediaElement on the page and passing Source uri string via Tag element. Tip from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287360/adding-media-element-in-windows-phone-7. Seems to be working now.

Comment: I ran into an issue. May be you can share your thoughts on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977672/need-clarification-on-using-audio-on-button-click-background-audio-etc-in-wind

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I get the error at the 6th media element. I try to put 14 Media Elements in a project (just to see what happens). You could also use SoundEffect from XNA if you really need to have a lot of sources playing at the same time or something